# Analyzing Android APK

Tags: java, android, kotlin, apk

After Analyzing Android APK I noticed there is ***lib*** folder one of the APK file components
And it taking too much from the Whole APK file size, After searching I realised that :

> lib/: Contains the compiled code that is specific to the software
> layer of a processor. This directory contains a subdirectory for each
> platform type, like armeabi, armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64, and
> mips.

So My question is how to optimize this file? and Is it important to have it inside APKs
or its ok to exclude it in build file , or use include native lib = false

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9844279?hl=en

Comment: @MartinZeitler the link you have shared not adding any info related to what I'm asking for , thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

You can create APKs for specific CPU types. This way only the code for that specific ABI (Application Binary Interface) will be included.

Check out this guide how to configure it in gradle: [Build multiple APKs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split)

Alternatively if you only want to upload your app to the Google Play Store anyway, you can create an Android App Bundle (AAB) and upload this. The Play Store will automatically generate APKs for different device configurations and offer smaller APKs to the end users.